# "This workbook contains external data. Do you want Microsoft Excel to clear the data before saving" prompt

Tags: excel

I have created a macro-enabled template, which contains only a empty dataset sheet sourced to a number of pivot tables.

Every time I try to save the template proper, or even a new workbook based on the template, I get the error:

```
This workbook contains external data. Do you want Microsoft Excel to clear the data before saving the template, and then automatically refresh the data whenever the template is opened?
```

There are no connections in data>connections>connections.
Edit Links is grayed-out in data>connections.

I have downloaded and ran "https://www.manville.org.uk/software/findlink.htm" with no links found.

The only item in formulas>name manager the dataset table with no external link.

I have unchecked file>options>advanced>ask to update automatic links.
I have enabled all items in file>options>trust center>external content.

I can't find anything in my VBA code that would cause an error like this.

This error prompt haunts me. Why is it doing this?

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a formula in a cell or a define name that points to an external file. Do a search for "HTTP" in your workbook and review your define name.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it's just a source template thing. Once I open a new document from the template, that warning doesn't come up.